# Why fstream is not inherited from ifstream and ofstream in c++?

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream, ofstream

`ifstream` and `ofstream` is for input and output in file, and `fstream` can do task of both them but not inherited from either of `ifstream` and `ofstream`, is this code repetition or something else?

[image: Hierarchy of fstream]

Comment: `ifstream` and and `ofstream` are for convienence, `fstream` is where the real work gets done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to ask the author, Bjarne Stroustrup, for a definitive answer. In his original paper on iostreams published in USENIX Proceedings of 1985, he seems to put a lot of emphasis on efficiency:

> Inline expanded functions are used for the basic operations (like "put a character into a buffer"), so the basic overhead tend to be one function call per simple object (integer, string, etc.) written (or read) plus one function call per buffer overflow.

So that could be the reason.

I guess you *could* extract common file I/O functionality into a mixin, but that would require `virtual` inheritance in order to allow for the diamond inheritance, which would add an extra indirection when accessing the underlying `basic_filebuf`.

In addition, as a file read/write mode normally cannot be changed once the file is opened, being able to cast `fstream` to `ifstream` or `ofstream` would create inconsistencies as you could get a writable `ifstream` or a readable `ofstream`.